# glReadPixels causes crash

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I'm trying to convert mouse coordinates into world coordinates. I'm using OpenGL 3.3 with GLFW and GLM for the math.

If I try to run my application, Visual Studio 2019 throws an exception whenever I use `glReadPixels` with `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` as format and `GL_FLOAT` as a type together. This happens only with an Intel graphics card, if it's an Nvidia card it works fine.

The exception is the following:

> ```
> Exception thrown at 0x047C1E88 (ig11icd32.dll) in app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation while reading path 0x000000F0.
> ```

I'm using an Intel(R) UHD Graphics

This is the code

```c++
    int pixelW = NULL;
    int pixelH = NULL;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window.getID(), &pixelW, &pixelH);

    glm::fvec2 screenSize = static_cast<glm::fvec2>(window.getSize());
    glm::fvec2 screenPos = static_cast<glm::fvec2>(sgl::Mouse::getPosition(window));
    glm::fvec2 pixelPos = screenPos * glm::fvec2(pixelW, pixelH) / screenSize;
    pixelPos += glm::fvec2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    glm::fvec3 win(pixelPos.x, pixelH - pixelPos.y, 0.0f);

    //The exception is thrown in this line
    glReadPixels(static_cast<GLint>(win.x), static_cast<GLint>(win.y), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &win.z);

    m_position = static_cast<glm::dvec3>(glm::unProject(win,
        camera,
        projection,
        glm::fvec4(0.0f, 0.0f, pixelW, pixelH)));
```

I've tried changing OpenGL version and using another type instead of GL_FLOAT (for example GL_DOUBLE), but it still doesn't work. I also made sure the depth buffer was enabled.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `int pixelW = NULL;` is wrong. C++ doesn't have any "null" values, and `NULL` is an old C-compatibility macro for null *pointers*.

Comment: What are win.x and win.y on the failing call?

Comment: In reply to stark: win.x and win.y are the 2D mouse coordinates

Comment: I think what @stark wants to know, is what are their *values* when the crash happens? And how large is your window?

Comment: @Some programmer dude
oops, my bad. My window is 850x500 and the values are based on my cursor position, so in this case they are x: 564.5 and y: 281.5

Comment: Oh, little update. I just noticed that it works only when the window gets created with the cursor outside it

Comment: It also crashes when I try to resize the window

Comment: Does the default framebuffer even have a depth buffer?

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes, it does

Comment: @Alessandro How can you know?

Comment: The only input that may generate access violation is if destination buffer is too small to hold the read pixels. Does not appear to be the case. Any other bad input should result in GL error, not exception. Ex: `GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if format is GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and there is no depth buffer.` Whatever the error is it's not in the code sample. Since it's working on other cards I'd blame the driver.

Comment: Related, but unlikely the problem: `If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER target (see glBindBuffer) while a block of pixels is requested, data is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store rather than a pointer to client memory.`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation - `glReadPixels` was crashing on Intel.
I replaced `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` by `GL_RGB` and had no crash.